# Computer won't boot after shutdown/reboot

Tags: boot, grub2

I currently have a Toshiba Satellite C660D which dual boots Ubuntu 14.04 (I had same issue with 13.10) and Windows 8.

Every time I shutdown or reboot my laptop from Ubuntu, I can only get it back on if I first run Boot-Repair. It seems as if it can't read the SSD, since it just hangs before the grub screen.

I found out that it's not being solved by using Boot-Rrepair. After just booting from another live USB, and immediately turning it back off, it works as well.

Comment: Do you have Fast Boot enabled in your BIOS? I had a similar problem and disabling it solved it for me.

Comment: I didn't, I tried enabling it, but that didn't work as well.